# Create azure application through Az module and assign API permissions using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell

I have written a script which creates azure application using Az module, creates secret key, assigns owner. But assigning API permission gives `insufficient permission error`. The user is an admin user. Still unable to assign API permission. What wrong am I doing?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
Connect-AzAccount
Import-Module Az.Resources
$tenant = Get-AzTenant
Set-AzContext -TenantId $tenant.Id
$AppName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Application name '
$myApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $AppName -IdentifierUris "http://$AppName.com"
Write-Host "App registered.."
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $myApp.ApplicationId -Role Owner
Write-Host "Service principal registered.."
$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddYears(100)
$secret = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter App Secret Key ' -AsSecureString
$secPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $secret
New-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId $myApp.ObjectId  -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate -Password $secPassword

$ResourceAppIdURI = "https://graph.windows.net/"
# $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$authority = "https://login.windows.net/$tenant/oauth2/token"
$ClientCred = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential" -ArgumentList $myApp.ApplicationId, $secret
$AuthContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority,$false
$AuthContext.TokenCache.Clear()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
$Token = $Authcontext.AcquireTokenAsync($ResourceAppIdURI, $ClientCred)

$AuthHeader = @{"Authorization" = $Token.Result.CreateAuthorizationHeader();"Content-Type"="application/json"}
$url = "https://graph.windows.net/$tenant/applications/$($myApp.ObjectID)?api-version=1.6"
Write-Host "URL: " $url

$postData = "{`"requiredResourceAccess`":[{`"resourceAppId`":`"00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`",
`"resourceAccess`":[{`"id`":`"e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d`",`"type`":`"Scope`"}]}]}";
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method "PATCH" -Headers $AuthHeader -Body $postData
Write-Host "Result of App API permission: " $result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call Azure AAD graph API to assign permissions with OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow, we need to provide enough permissions(Azure AD Graph -> Aapplication permissions -> **Application.ReadWrite.All**)

[image]

Besides, regarding how to assign permissions to AD application with PowerShell, we also can use PowerShell module [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0).

For example

```
Connect-AzureAD
$AppAccess = [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess]@{
    ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000";
    ResourceAccess =
        [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]@{
            Id = "";
            Type = ""},
        [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]@{
            Id = "";
            Type = ""}
}
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <the app object id> -RequiredResourceAccess $AppAccess
```

## Update

According to my test, when we use Az module, we can use the following method to get access token and call AAD graph rest API. But please note that when you use the method, the account you use to run `Connect-AzAccount` should be Azure AD [Global Admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles)

```
Connect-AzAccount

$context =Get-AzContext
$dexResourceUrl='https://graph.windows.net/'
$token = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, 
                                $context.Environment, 
                                $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(),
                                 $null, 
                                 [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, 
                                 $null, $dexResourceUrl).AccessToken

# assign permissions
$headers =@{}
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $($token)")
$body = "{
`n    `"requiredResourceAccess`": [{
`n            `"resourceAppId`": `"00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`",
`n            `"resourceAccess`": [
`n              {
`n                  `"id`": `"405a51b5-8d8d-430b-9842-8be4b0e9f324`",
`n                  `"type`": `"Role`"
`n              },
`n              {
`n                  `"id`": `"09850681-111b-4a89-9bed-3f2cae46d706`",
`n                  `"type`": `"Role`"
`n              }
`n          ]
`n        }
`n    ]
`n}
`n"
$url ='https://graph.windows.net/hanxia.onmicrosoft.com/applications/d4975420-841f-47d5-a3d2-0870901f13cd?api-version=1.6'
Invoke-RestMethod $url  -Method 'PATCH' -Headers $headers -Body $body

#check if adding the permissions you need
$headers =@{}
$headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $($token)")
$url ='https://graph.windows.net/hanxia.onmicrosoft.com/applications/<aad application object id>?api-version=1.6'
$response=Invoke-RestMethod $url  -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers 
$response.requiredResourceAccess | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

Comment: I am using Az module and not AzureAD module. Any idea how to give permissions in Az module? What is the powershell version you're using with AzureAD module?

Comment: @Alva, Now the reason you get the error is that when you get the access token to call AAD graph API (`https://graph.windows.net/`), you do not provide the enough permissions.  And according to the script you provided, you create an ADD application then you directly use it to get AD access token. It is wrong. Becasue the application does not have the ADD graph API permissions. Please create another application and add api permissions (Azure AD Graph -> Aapplication permissions -> Application.ReadWrite.All) in Azure portal. Then use the application to get token and call aad graph.

Comment: Thank you so much Jim. That helped. I would also like to give admin consent for those API permissions. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the easiest way to do this without messing around with http requests, was to combine the `Azure-powershell` module and the `Az cli` module

So, once I have created my new app:

`$myApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $AppName -IdentifierUris "http://$AppName.com"`

Then I would login into azure using the `Az Cli`, and, for instance:

- Add some api permissions
- Grant these permissions directory admin consent ( if needed )

```
. { $azcliLogin = az login }
. { az account set --subscription $config.subscriptionId }
. { az ad app permission add --id $myApp.appid --api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 --api-permissions 78c8a3c8-a07e-4b9e-af1b-b5ccab50a175=Role }
. { $appApiGrant = az ad app permission grant --id $config.azureAccess.appid --api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 }
. { az ad app permission admin-consent --id $myApp.appid }
```

Where:

`--api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` Refers to Microsoft Graph API

`--api-permissions 78c8a3c8-a07e-4b9e-af1b-b5ccab50a175=Role` Refers to some role on this api, as Directory.ReadWrite.All

> You can get the required API and API-PERMISSIONS guids from the App manifiest in Azure
>   [image]

This way you create the app with the required granted api permissions, in a single powershell script.

Comment: i guess this is the way to go, even though I think microsoft must provide this functionality in the az-module

Comment: This was done more than a year ago... they may have improved the module ;)

Comment: ... they didn't ...